# Select the contents respective to some specific content from a file and move it to an output file

Tags: shell-script, files, oracle, csplit

I have a file tnsnames.ora and its contents are as below.

```
NEWDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = linuxerp.de.mph.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = linuxerp.de.mph.com)(PORT = 1550))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = newdb)
    )
  )

LISTENER_DG11G =
  (ADDRESS_LIST =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = linuxerp.de.mph.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = linuxerp.de.mph.com)(PORT = 1550))
  )

LISTENER_SABDB =
  (ADDRESS_LIST =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = linuxerp.de.mph.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = linuxerp.de.mph.com)(PORT = 1550))
  )

STEST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = linuxerp.de.mph.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = STEST)
    )
  )

RBSDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = linuxerp.de.mph.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = RBSDB)
     )
    )
```

In the above file `NEWDB =` `LISTENER_DG11G =` `LISTENER_SABDB =` `STEST =` `RBSDB =` are the database names and the respective service  names are included in `SERVICE_NAME =`

So, From the above file I am trying to extract the Database name and respective service names and put it into a file or .xls in linux.

The output file should be like

```
NEWDB   newdb
STEST   STEST
RBSDB   RBSDB
```

And what all databases that don't have service name should not be added into the output file.

I tried using `CSPLIT` and move the first set of lines  to a file "X" and select the first line and SERVICE_NAME using `cat X | grep -i "SERVICE_NAME" | cut -d "=" -f2 | rev | cut -d ")" -f2 | rev | awk "NF"`
and move it to a file and append the same way to rest of database names.

But it seems so complicated. Any other idea how it can be done will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are better ways of handling this, but this pair of `awk` scripts will do the job. You can use either the enlarged version with comments or the one-liner below; they're functionally identical.

```
awk '
    BEGIN { RS="" }                             # Slurp paragraphs
    { print gensub("\n", " ", "g") }            # Replace NL with SPACE
' /tmp/tnsnames.ora |                           # ...in this file

awk '
    /SERVICE_NAME/ {                            # Only process matching lines
        listener=$1;                            # Listener is the first field
        si=NF-2;                                # Count fields back from end of string
        service=gensub(")", "", 1, $si);        # Strip trailing ")"
        printf "%s\t%s\n", listener, service    # Output result
    }
'
```

Sample run

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="" } { print gensub("\n", " ", "g") }' /tmp/tnsnames.ora | awk '/SERVICE_NAME/ { listener=$1; si=NF-2; service=gensub(")", "", 1, $si);  printf "%s\t%s\n", listener, service }'
NEWDB   newdb
STEST   STEST
RBSDB   RBSDB
```

Comment: Hey @roaima. Thanks Man. That was an awesome awk script. And it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -l -00ne '
my ($blk) = /^\w+/g;

$np = qr/
   \(              # match an opening paren
     (?:
      (?> [^)(]+ ) # one or more non paren, non backtracking
           |
      (??{ $np })  # recurse for more
     )*
   \)              # match a closing paren
/x;

1 while
   /$np
     (?{
        m{ \( CONNECT_DATA \s+ = (?:\s*$np\s*)+ \) }x and
        m{ \( SERVICE_NAME \s+ = \s+ (\w+)      \) }x and
           print join $", $blk, $1 for $&;
     })
   /gx;
' input_file
```

## Output

```
NEWDB newdb
STEST STEST
RBSDB RBSDB
```

Comment: +1 I do like `perl`'s powerful REs. In particular that it's so easy to extract a value from a variable-position string like `SERVICE_NAME = {servicename}`.